# How to exclude all combinations of lowercase (a-z) using RegExpTokenizer?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, list, nltk

I need to remove all the lowercase letter combinations using the `pattern` option of `regexptokenizer`. Is there exist any way?

What i have tried is as follows:

```
import re
from nltk import regexp_tokenize
data = {'fresh air', 'entertainment system', 'ice cream', 'milk', 'dog', 'blood pressure', 'body temperature', 'car', 'ac', 'auto', 'air quality'}
data = {i: i.replace(" ", "_") for i in data}
pattern = re.compile(r"\b("+"|".join(data)+r")\b")
text_file = ['A is\'s vitamin-d in===(milk) "enough, carrying 321 active automatic body hi+al.', '{body temperature} [try] to=== improve air"s quality level by automatic intake of fresh air.', 'turn on the tv or entertainment system based on that individual preferences', 'blood pressure monitor', 'I buy more ice cream', 'proper method to add frozen wild blueberries in ice cream']
result = [pattern.sub(lambda x: "{}".format(data[x.group()]), i) for i in text_file]
tokens = [[word for word in regexp_tokenize(word, pattern=r"\s|[0-9!()\-+\$%;,.:@'\"/={}\[\]\']", gaps=True)] for word in result]  
print(tokens)
```

Note: I need the output preserving its current form. All that I need is only to exclude the lower case single letters. Thanks in Advance.

The addition of `[^a-z]` not at all working for me and it's omitting the injected underscore symbol in some words, which I can't afford to lose.

Comment: What regex are you attempting to use and on what string ? Can't you simplify it while asking the question, until a basic solution is found ?

Comment: The normal way to exclude lowercase letters is to confine them to a class of other characters as well. `[^\Wa-z]` or just to exclude them in a class of acceptable characters `[_)(\dA-Z':;/]`, etc ...

Comment: I am very new to regex. I am trying to learn. Thanks for your response.

Comment: I know the normal way, i.e. `[^a-z]+`, but it's not working in my case as the strings are of mixed format combination of several special characters. What else I need to add in the `pattern` as mentioned above in the question to exclude all the lower case letters in the above text file. I hope this is more clear.

Comment: `[^a-z]` matches over 1 million Unicode characters, are you sure you want to use that without qualification ?

Comment: What you _ADD_ in the pattern is what you want. If you want some punctuation, some upper case letters, some numbers, that's what you add to the character class `[here]` By default, what you _don't_ want (add) is excluded ..

Comment: Exactly @sln. For me, as of now, the pattern = r"\s|[\\A-Z0-9!<|`#~>?()\-+\$%;,.:@'\"/={}\[\]\'].|[^\w a-z]` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```py
pattern=r"\s|[0-9!()\-+\$%;,.:@'\"/={}\[\]\'].|[^\w a-z]"
```

Comment: Thank you shweta. I too have tried this without `.` symbol. Your suggested pattern omits the injected `_` symbol, which I don't want to lose. How to exclude the lower case single letters in the above example while preserving the existing structure? If you have any idea, please suggest.

Comment: @MishraS - To keep "_" symbol, try this pattern : pattern=r"\s|[0-9!()\-+\$%;,.:@'\"/={}\[\]\'].|[^\wa-z]|"

Comment: Thanks Shweta. Add this to the solution. Actually `pattern=r"\s|[\\A-Z0-9!<|`#~>?()\-+\$%;,.:@'\"/={}\[\]\'].|[^\w a-z]` helps to achieve what I was looking for. Thanks edit this in your answer.